# How to go from solution in exponentials to solution in $\sin$ and $\cos$ for $y''+ay'+by=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the differential equation $y''+ay'+by=0$.

If the discriminant $d$ of $r^2+ar=b=0$ is negative then we know that the roots of this equation are complex conjugates.

The solution to the DE is then

$$y(x)=e^{-ax^2/2}\left (c_1\sin{\left (\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{-d}\right )}+c_2\cos{\left (\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{-d}\right )}\right )\tag{1}$$

If the discriminant is positive, then we have two real roots $r_1$ and $r_2$ and the solution is

$$y(x)= c_1e^{r_1x}+c_2e^{r_2x} \tag{2}$$

I believe I read that we can make (1) become (2), that is, (2) is also true when we have complex roots.

**How do we get from (1) or (2) or vice-versa when we have complex roots.**

Take for example $y''+4y=0$. Then $d=-16$ and the roots are $\pm 2i$.

If we use (1) we get the solution $$y(x)=c_1\sin{(2x)}+c_2\cos{(2x)}\tag{3}$$

If we use (2) then we have

$$y(x)=c_1e^{2xi}+c_2e^{-2xi}$$

$$=c_1(\cos{(2x)}+i\sin{(2x)})+c_2(\cos{(-2x)}+i\sin{(-2x)})$$

Now, since $\cos{x}=\cos{-x}$ and $\sin{x}=-\sin{(-x)}$ then

$$=(c_1+c_2)\cos{2x}+i(c_1-c_2)\sin{2x}$$

**This expression is not quite (3).**

Comment: You forgot a minus sign in the $\sin$ in the line before "now, since[...]"

Comment: Relabel the constants, say, $C_1 = c_1 + c_2$ and likewise. Done.

Comment: Can the constants be complex?

Answer (score 2):

For second linear ODE with real constant coefficients $y''+ay'+by=0$, if $a^2-4b\neq0$, then it has two different roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\in\mathbb{C}$. Of course $\lambda_1\neq\lambda_2$, the DE has general solution $C_{1}e^{\lambda_1}x+C_{2}e^{\lambda_2}x$ where $C_{1},C_{2}$ can be any real constants.

Set $\lambda_1=a+ib$ when $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Then by Euler's identity, $C_{1}e^{\lambda_1 x}=C_{1}e^{(a+ib)x}=C_{1}e^{ax}\cos(bx)+iC_{1}e^{ax}\sin(bx)$.
Similarly, $C_{2}e^{\lambda_2 x}=C_{2}e^{(a-ib)x}=C_{2}e^{ax}\cos(bx)-iC_{2}e^{ax}\sin(bx)$. They're two complex-valued solutions to this DE.

Generally, for $y''+ay'+by=u(x)+iv(x)$ where $u,v$ are real functions, if it has one complex solution $y=U(x)+iV(x)$, then its conjugate $\bar{y}=U(x)-iV(x)$ is another one solution. And, the real part of $y$ i.e. $U(x)$ is the real-valued solution to $y''+ay'+by=u(x)$, the imaginary part of $y$ i.e. $V(x)$ is the real-valued solution to $y''+ay'+by=v(x)$.

Back to this DE, it has two complex solutions $e^{\lambda_1 x},e^{\lambda_2 x}$, then the real part $e^{ax}\cos(bx)$ and the imaginary part $e^{ax}\sin(bx)$ are two real-valued functions to this DE, the general solution is $$C_{1}e^{ax}\cos(bx)+C_{2}e^{ax}\sin(bx)$$ where $C_{1},C_{2}$ are any two $\textbf{real}$ constants.

In your question, the expression $(c_1+c_2)\cos 2x+i(c_1-c_2)\sin 2x$ is no problem, but you need to take real and imaginary part at last step and rewrite the constants. It is $$(c_1+c_2)\cos 2x=C_1\cos 2x,\quad(c_1-c_2)\sin 2x=C_2\sin 2x$$ and the constants are all $\textbf{real}$.

Comment: In the very last equation what happened to the $i$?

Comment: The imaginary part is the real-valued solution to it, so $i$ needn't to be appeared.

Comment: I understand your argument now. From the complex-valued solution to $y''+ay'+by=0$ you are saying that the real and imaginary parts of the function are each a real solution to this differential equation. Thus, we can take a linear combination of them. But I still have this question: is there a way to show this result using only algebraic manipulations of the equations?

Comment: If followed what you have done, that is, by equation $(2): y= e^{2xi}+e^{-2xi}$, and you used Euler's identity to rewrite it,  $\cos(2x)+i\sin(2x))+(\cos(2x)+i\sin(-2x))$. Because they're conjugate. To get real-valued solutions, you can calculate one by $\text{Re}=\frac{1}{2}(\cos(2x)+\cos(2x))$ and another one by $\text{Im}=\frac{1}{2i}(i\sin(2x)-i\sin(-2x))$.